# Firestore security rules for role based access

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to implement role based security into my Firestore database but having trouble getting the necessary data needed to make access decisions.

I have a `users` collection containing group membership under the `roles` map with group permissions described at two levels: 'member' and 'admin'

Example user document:

```
{
    name: "User1",
    roles: { group1: "admin", group2: "member"... }
}
```

I would like to allow the owner of a `user` document to be able to:

- Update all fields apart from the `roles` map

Also, I would like a user who is a group admin to be able to:

- Modify another user's `roles` map but only to a group that he has an admin role to

Example unit test:

```
it("[users] group admin can update user's roles if admin of destination group", async () => {
    const admin = adminApp({ uid: "admin" });
    const alice = authedApp({ uid: "alice" });

    // Create user document for alice and make 'admin' of group1
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(
        admin.collection("users")
        .doc("alice")
        .set({ name: "Alice", roles: { group1: "admin" } })
    );

    // Create user document for bob but without any group membership
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(
        admin.collection("users")
        .doc("bob")
        .set({ name: "Bob" })
    );

    // Alice should be able to grant bob membership to group1
    // as she is an 'admin' of group1
    await firebase.assertSucceeds(
        alice.collection("users")
        .doc("bob")
        .update({ 'roles.group1': "member" })
    );

    // Alice should NOT be able to grant bob membership to group2
    // as she is not an 'admin' of group2
    await firebase.assertFails(
        alice.collection("users")
        .doc("bob")
        .update({ 'roles.group2': "member" })
    );
});
```

And the rules I have so far:

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {
    function isSignedIn() {
        return request.auth != null;
    }

    function isOwner(rsc) {
        return isSignedIn() && request.auth.uid == rsc.id;
    }

    function notUpdating(field) {
        return !(field in request.resource.data)
            || resource.data[field] == request.resource.data[field]
    }

    function requestorIsAdminOfGroup(groupId) {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.roles[groupId] == "admin"
    }

    function adminUpdateUsersRole() {
        // Get document before update
        let before = resource.data;

        // Get potential document after update 
        let after = getAfter(request.path).data;

        // Compare to find top level document keys with changes
        let affectedKeys = after.diff(before).affectedKeys();

        // Find keys in roles that have changes (groupIds)
        let affectedGroups = after.roles.diff(before.roles).affectedKeys();

        // What I'm trying to do here:
        // - Ensure that only the 'roles' field is changing by checking
        //   affected key name and size
        // - Ensure that a single groupId is being modified and that the
        //   requesting user is an 'admin' of that group
        //
        // Problem: how do I get the key name of the modified key from the 'roles' map
        // in order to pass to requestorIsAdminOfGroup?
        return affectedKeys.size() == 1 && affectedKeys.hasOnly(["roles"]) &&
            affectedGroups.size() == 1 && requestorIsAdminOfGroup(groupId)

    }

    match /users/{userId} {
        allow update: if (isOwner(resource) && notUpdating("roles")) || adminUpdateUsersRole();
    }
}
```

My problem is highlighted with comments above in `adminUpdateUsersRole()`

How can I get the changing key in the `roles` map representing a groupId in order to verify that the requestor is an admin of that group?

If this is not possible, I am also open to suggestions which change the structure of the `users` collection while achieving the same goal of enabling group admins to manage group membership.

Comment: I'll just point out that this would be a lot easier if the roles were stored in documents other than the user's own document.  Per-group documents in a subcollection would be much easier to manage all around.

Comment: If roles were stored as a sub-collection of users on a per-group basis, I'm struggling to see how a security rule could be written to find common groups between two users. I'm not aware of being able to use `get()` to find a list of a collection's keys. Can you provide an example of how this would work in practice?